# zsh configuration for Catalina

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, zsh

macOS Catalina now is using zsh but I was already using zsh and Hyper terminal so I wanted to make sure my zshrc configuration was ok. Everything seems ok except my RStudio/Anaconda installation might have some issues. I'm not sure why Anaconda has such a long script during so maybe you can tell me if I need it or not.

I have `.zshrc`, `.zprofile`, `.profile` and `.bash_profile` files. As well as `.oh-my-zsh` and `.zsh` folders.  What is essential and what can I remove?

Also it seems I used to have a path like 
`/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:/Users/ty604/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet` but it some how got automatically removed. Would Catalina have removed that?

Here is my current `.zshrc` file.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/ty604/flutter/bin"

export PATH=/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/ty604/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/ty604/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<


# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/ty604/.oh-my-zsh"

plugins=(
git
#zsh-syntax-highlighting
#zsh-autosuggestions
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

autoload -U promptinit; promptinit
prompt pure

source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
source ~/.zsh/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

.profile and .zprofile both contain 
`export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to keep your `.zshrc` file. Everything else is not essential. In fact, I would highly recommend you ditch Oh-My-Zsh, since you already have a custom prompt and are not using any of its plugins anyway. It will speed up your terminal quite a bit. (OMZ's git "plugin" is just a bunch of aliases. You don't need it.)

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see your answer until now since I had long since fixed it. Thanks. Yeah I'm just using Zsh and Hyper.